# Subscribing to list changes using ListSubscriptionFactory: failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: list, spfx, spfx-webparts, subscriptions

I followed the [Subscribe to list notifications article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/subscribe-to-list-notifications#get-notified-of-changes-to-documents-stored-in-a-sharepoint-document-library). I was able to get notified when list items were added or updated. The code:

```
export default class BookingRequestsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IBookingRequestsWebPartProps> {
  private _listSubscriptionFactory: ListSubscriptionFactory;
  private _listSubscription: IListSubscription;

  private createListSubscription(): void {
    console.log("Creating subscription... wait.");
    this._listSubscriptionFactory = new ListSubscriptionFactory(this);
    this._listSubscriptionFactory.createSubscription({
      domain: '<site domain>.sharepoint.com',
      siteId: Guid.parse('b6a831ad-fce7-4fad-a04b-745be38a43f3'),
      webId: Guid.parse('6ac9cb5e-2aa3-4b24-aa57-da33c61f29d1'),
      listId: Guid.parse('dae5e072-1992-45eb-9b14-f6df46a2a80a'),
      callbacks: {
        notification: this._loadDocuments.bind(this),
        connect: this._subscriptionConnected.bind(this),
        disconnect: this._subscriptionDisconnected.bind(this)
      }
    });
  }

  private _loadDocuments(): void {

    // load documents here
    console.log("something changed!");

  }

  private _subscriptionConnected(): void {
    // code to execute when the subscription to the list has been established
    console.log("the list has been established", this._listSubscription);
  }

  private _subscriptionDisconnected(reason: string): void {
    // code to execute when the connection to the list has been disconnected
    console.log("the connection to the list has been disconnected", this._listSubscription);
  }

// unrelated webpart code coninues here.
```

It works great:

[image]

There *is* this an error present despite the fact that I am subscribed:
[image]

But after about ~60 seconds, I lose my list subscription and get a ton of errors:

[image]

**Question:** Does anyone know what can be done? Anything I am doing wrong? Why am I disconnected after a connection was established?

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-list-subscription": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.11.0",
    "@pnp/pnpjs": "^2.0.13",
    "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "^2.6.0-beta.81ae005",
    "@pnp/spfx-property-controls": "2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.155.3",
    "react": "16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "16.8.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a know issue [logged in GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6477). For me the problem seems to come and go and the errors appear to indicate attempts to re-establish the connection. There is a "disconnect" message when the errors start and a "connect" message when they stop. So I treat the "connect" message like a change notification and re-fetch the data.

```
private createListSubscription(): void {
  const siteInfo = this.props.siteInfo;

  this.props.listSubscriptionFactory.createSubscription({
    siteId: siteInfo.itemsWebId != undefined ? Guid.parse(siteInfo.itemsSiteId) : undefined,
    webId: siteInfo.itemsWebId != undefined ? Guid.parse(siteInfo.itemsWebId) : undefined,
    listId: siteInfo.itemsWebId != undefined ? Guid.parse(siteInfo.itemsListId) : undefined,
    callbacks: {
      notification: this.onListUpdate.bind(this),
      connect: this.onListSubscriptionConnected.bind(this),
      disconnect: this.onListSubscriptionDisconnected.bind(this)
    }
  }).then(newSub => this._listSubscription = newSub);
}

private onListSubscriptionConnected(): void {
  console.log('subscription connected message');
  this.updateLocations();
}

private onListSubscriptionDisconnected(reason: string): void {
  console.log(`subscription disconnected message: ${reason}`);
}

private onListUpdate() {
  this.updateLocations();
}
```

Comment: As of today, this is still a bug that only Microsoft can fix.