# How to establish a real time connection to a list item using SharePoint Rest API

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, sitepages

On my SharePoint home page I have a notification element that is ajax'd from a list item from the same site collection. I would like the user to always (or as often as possible) see the latest information from the list item.

I can do short polling where I'm sending an ajax request to the API to get the list item, say every 20 seconds.

Is there a more efficient way or a way to show latest information in less than 20 seconds intervals?

I am the site collection admin and not a site admin, so can't run any shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing out-of-the-box like this. But you can still pull your list every 20-30 seconds. Just use a filter to get the latest items with modified date > previous poll. Most of the time, there will be 0 items returned, so these queries should not be very expensive.

Comment: Thank you Denis! Yes i looked up odata queries after posting this question(someone on this site recommended similar approach but in CAML) . After a long research, I reached the same conclusion as what you are recommending.

Comment: That should work. Because I am already using this approach, but in SharePoint Online, in SPFx webparts. If someone is interested, there is a client-side update event we can subscribe to, but the issue is that it does not really work as of today: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293998/subscribing-to-list-changes-using-listsubscriptionfactory-failed-websocket-is